# Firebase nodejs serve error "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path"

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Getting below error message after issuing command "firebase serve --only functions,hosting"

```
!  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:594:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at InitializeFirebaseAdminStubs (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:231:18)
    at C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:451:9
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at main (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:421:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sushanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:511:5)
!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

Below are the commands i executed

1. firebase serve --only functions,hosting
   Got a message that i need to update from 6.4.0 -> 6.9.2 "Run npm i -g firebase-tools to update"
2. After updating again did ran serve and got message "Update available 6.9.2 → 6.10.0" and i again did ran the update.
3. Updated firebase-admin as well "npm i -g firebase-admin@latest"
4. Again ran "firebase serve --only functions,hosting" started seeing below message on firebase-functions-test. Ran the mentioned command in functions folder.

```
+  functions: Using node@8 from host.
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "D:\BigData\13. Firebase\FB-BTD\FB-BTD\functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
!  The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-functions-test" to be installed as a development dependency. To fix this, run "npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test" in your functions directory.
i  functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)
[hosting] Rewriting / to http://localhost:5001/btd-in2-20180718/us-central1/app for local Function app
i  functions: Beginning execution of "app"
!  The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-functions-test" to be installed as a development dependency. To fix this, run "npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test" in your functions directory.
```

5. Next time i run firebase serve, i am getting above error message.

Due to this i am not able to test locally the web nodejs firebase code.

Comment: Please post an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub.  Stack Overflow is not really the right place for bug reports.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Issue has been raised in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1337)

Downgrading to 6.8.0 worked!

Answer (score 0):

update Node version!, you used an oldest version.